# zsh completion: complete block devices in /dev

Tags: shell, zsh, devices, autocomplete, block-device

for my script, I need to complete block devices in `/dev`, so that when I do

```
my_script.sh <TAB>
```

it will complete `/dev/` and offer me all disks that are listed in `/dev` (not in subdirectories). So for example:

```
my_script.sh <TAB>
my_script.sh /dev/

my_script.sh /dev/<TAB>
sda sdb sdc mmcblk0p1

my_script.sh /dev/sd
sda sdb sdc
```

How should I modify my completion for that to work as described?

```
_arguments -S : \
    '--foo' \
    '--bar' \
    '*:file:_files'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
_arguments -S : \
    '--foo' \
    '--bar' \
    '*:block devices:(( /dev/*(-%b:t) ))'
```

`(-%b:t)` is a glob qualifier, `%b` to select block devices, `-` for that selection to be made after symlink resolution, the `:t` modifier to select only the `t`ail of those files.

You could use `_files`, and *benefit* from colouring for instance with:

```
_arguments -S : \
    '--foo' \
    '--bar' \
    '*:block devices:_files -W /dev -g "*(-%b)"'
```

Where we use the `-W` option of `_files` to specify `W`here to find those files, but that still offers subdirs of `/dev` so you can find further block devices in there.

If on Linux, you can use

```
    '*:block devices:_files -W /sys/class/block'
```

Or:

```
    '*:block devices:(( /sys/class/block/*(:t) ))'
```

To only get the kernel names of those block devices.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only looking for block devices, there are two separate steps required:

First you need to establish which of the special quasi-files inside of `/dev` are actually block devices. This can be done using `stat`. The command is fairly ubiquitous in unix, but if for some reason you do not have it in your distro you can install it with `apt install coreutils`.

The following command creates an array composed of full names of blockdevices (devices starting with 800) found inside /dev

```
blockdevs=($(stat -c "%t %n" /dev/* | grep "^8" | cut -d' ' -f2))
```

---

**NOTE:** If you are looking for more than just actual blockdevices, (not all filenames inside `/dev` are block devices. Aside from normal files, and directories, there will also be 'character special files' like of various subtypes like `/dev/tty` and `/dev/zero`, or symbolic links like `/dev/core`) you will need to edit the above array declaration.

---

Once you have the array, you then create the corresponding completion(the quotes are extremely important) based on its stored values:

```bash
compctl -g "${blockdevs}" my_script.sh
```

now if your command line starts with `my script.sh` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> , the completer will automatically fill in the starting prefix of `/dev/' and then display the names of blockdevices found in the top-most level of that directory (i.e.` /dev/.`).

This type of approach using array values works for all types of custom completions.
Basically all it does is check if the first word matches `myscript.sh` and then if no other input is detected as the second argument, it matches and displays only the filename (using the `(:t)` modifier) results found in `/dev`

Execute both code lines in a terminal , or add them both to ~/.zshrc to persist the completion.

Comment: The OP is using `zsh`, not `bash`. zsh has its own stat builtin and globbing qualifiers to select block devices

Comment: The ` compctl -k ...` comes straight from the manpages of `zshcompctl`. The `zsh/compctl` is a builtin module and comes with the main shell package. The `zsh` shell  certainly allows `compctl` in addition to their newer, and in my opinion far more cumbersome system. In fact, I don't think `bash` actually even has a `compctl` command, as I am only familiar with `compopt` `compgen` and `complete`.